# Where is the location of cl.exe of VS2015 msvc build tool (v140) in VS2022

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, visual-studio-2022, build-tools, cl.exe

Recently, I've installed VS2022 and installed the following tools
`msvc v140 - vs 2015 c++ build tools (v14.00),   msvc v141 - VS 2017 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.16),    msvc v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.29)` 
I found that when I installed the tools above, I could find three folders in

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC

that is
[image]
I fould folder named '14.16.27023' for VS2017 tool msvc v141, folder named '14.29.30133' is for VS2019 tool msvc v142 and folder named '14.38.33130' for VS2022 tool msvc v143. I also found that every folder above contains sub-directorie like '**bin\Hostx64\x64**' and has a **cl.exe** file in it.

What makes me confused is I can't find a folder and a** cl.exe** file for **VS2015-msvc-v140-tool**. I wanna ask why and where could I find the **cl.exe** file for **VS2015-msvc-v140-tool**.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Find it back in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin.  VS2017 and up are special in that their edition name is part of the install path.  Makes it hard to find the tools back, that's why it made a local copy.  VS2015 and older can simply be found in their install location.

Comment: Do you really need to know this location, or is this more out of interest? Using msbuild or VS and selecting the correct toolset in some way should make the right cl available, no matter where it is?

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your comment! I try to uninstall the tool of VS2015,  cleaned VS2015 remained files using VSUninstalled, and reinstalled the tool again using VSInstaller. I successfully find the tool under the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin.

Comment: @stijn Thank you for your advice. I'll try it!

Comment: For example, C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\Hostx86\arm 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\Hostx86\arm
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\Hostx64\arm
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\Hostx86\arm64